# How to control op amp gain with atmega 32 MCU?

Tags: operational-amplifier, atmega, gain

I am attempting to control the gain of an amplifier circuit I am building programmatically. I am using the atmega 32 MCU to control an LCD screen and take input from some buttons. Basically, I would like to include a volume up and down button that tell the MCU to change the amplifier gain.

The amplifier circuit is shown below and the 10k pot is circled in red:
[image: amp crkit]

I have thought of using a transistor to do PWM control in place of the 10k pot, but I was advised that this would not work and that I should use a resistor bank instead or perhaps a switch capacitor circuit.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, and is there any reason why I wouldnt be able to replace the potentiometer with a digital pot like this one: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10613 ??

Comment: Why not use an amp that has digital gain control in the first place?

Comment: why not use a digital resistor? usually they are I2C devices, with at least 256 steps, sometimes more if you pay for it. Can be linear or logarithmic.

Comment: What exactly is the nature of the signal you're going to amplify?

Answer (score 1):

I've used those exact pots. The datasheet is not kidding about the wiper current; don't exceed it at min/max and you should be fine.

Comment: Another thing to be careful about, you aren't supposed to have voltage going through the device that is outside the supply rails, so if your audio signal is zero-centered you need to offset it before the digital pot chip.

Answer (score 1):

None of the pot terminals can go below Vss. If your input doesn't go below ground you should be OK.  That and the current restrictions are the factors I usually have issues with

Comment: Wow, okay, so what is the simplest way to insure that my input will be in the 0-5v input range since the pot apparently cannot handle negative input voltage? The input I have is your typical mp3 player headphone signal.

Comment: Add an offset and another amp stage